# Exponent + square root + fraction: how to make look nice?

Tags: spacing, equations

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}}e^{i\sqrt{\frac{\omega\mu_0\sigma z}{2}}}\end{equation}
```

It is a fraction within a square root which is part of an exponent.

Any idea how to make this look nice? I have tried \dfrac, \vphantom, etc. but am looking for other ideas. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I think this off-topic, but I'd recommend using the `\exp{}` notation  and or / notation (i.e. (ωμ_0σz)/2)

Comment: `\exp(..)` may be

Comment: Also `\begin{equation}}`?

Comment: `\begin{equation}}` will just generate an error: please show the actual code you are using, preferably as a complete small document from `\documentclass`  to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

As posted there is an extra `}` so no real output at all (any output after an error is more or less accidental).

You can use a `\strut` to raise the subscript a bit (1)  but possibly better is to not make the subscript so big by not using the `\frac` form (2) or not using a superscript on e at all (3).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}e\strut^{i\sqrt{\frac{\omega\mu_0\sigma z}{2}}}\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}e\strut^{i\sqrt{\omega\mu_0\sigma z/2}}\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}\exp(i(\tfrac{1}{2}\omega\mu_0\sigma z)^{\frac{1}{2}})\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: here's a place where just slightly bigger parentheses would look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `\strut` before `^` raises the exponent higher and the usage of `\mathstrut` in the nominator does the root symbol bigger.

```
$$e\strut^{i\sqrt{\mathstrut \omega \mu_0 \sigma z \over 2}}$$
```